# storeRefs in Vue3 and Pinia returns object instead of array

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a store called `utilStore` to store the latitude and longitude of the user in an array defined like this:

```
// src/stores/utilStore.js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
export const useUtilStore = defineStore("UtilStore", {
    state: () => (        {
        userLatLng: [],
        userLocationLoading: false // ignore this
    }),
    actions: {
        fillUserLatLng(latLng) {
            this.userLatLng = latLng;
        }
    }
})
```

In ComponentA, I update the state of the store by calling `fillUserLatLng`, so that other components also have access to the location of the user:

```
// src/components/ComponentA.vue
<template>
    <ComponentB/>
</template>

<script setup>
import ComponentB from "@/components/ComponentB";
import { useUtilStore } from '@/stores/UtilStore.js'

onMounted(() => {
  const utilStore = useUtilStore()
  utilStore.fillUserLatLng([52.512494,13.326988])
})
</script>
```

In ComponentB, I just show the latitude and longited and print them also to console:

```
// src/components/ComponentB.vue
<template>
    {{userLatLng}}
</template>
<script setup>
import {defineEmits, defineProps, reactive, ref, toRefs, watch} from 'vue'
import {useUtilStore} from '@/stores/UtilStore.js'
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";

const utilStore = useUtilStore()
const {userLatLng} = storeToRefs(utilStore)
console.log(userLatLng)
console.log(userLatLng[0])
</script>
```

When I run this, 52.512494,13.326988 gets displayed in the html as [52.512494,13.326988] which is as expected.
But when I open the console to see the console.log() outputs, it looks like this:
[image: screenshot of firefox console]

As you can see, the correct values [52.512494, 13.326988] are in there. But I get an object instead of an array, as I would expect (see the undefined undefined at the top of the screenshot)
Where is the mistake?

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong, this is expected.  `storeToRefs` returns refs.  Refs wrap their values in proxy objects.  These are automatically unwrapped when used in `<template>`.  The inner value can be accessed in your script code by using `.value`, e.g. `console.log(userLatLng.value[0])` See the Vue documentation on [Reactivity fundamentals](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html) for a more in-depth explanation (make sure you toggle the docs to show "Composition API" in the top left).